# SFML Render Screen not Visible

Tags: sfml

I've downloaded this code : https://github.com/AlexZihaoXu/CppFlappyBird
I used DevC++ with SFML.
Compiler Gives 0 Errors.
but when I run it it displays nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have downloaded and compiled it, works perfectly. What do you see on the screen? For example, when I delete the res folder, I just see a yellow screen.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @chiuyus. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so it's easier for others to help you.